# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() Android 11, 12 and 13. How to fix?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

On Samsung, Motorola devices im getting this error. Honestly i surfed whole internet and most of stackoverflow, as google and everyone is saying use worker etc but honestly with worker reminders are not working on time so after combining everything, i have build some code but i getting this error. also i dont wish to show constant running notification in android to make my foreground service work. I know many apps use something i dont know

Error:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{2d6cc65 u0 com.simplifymindfulness.melatonin/.service.RescheduleAlarmsService}
   at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2147)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:310)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2376)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
   
   
 Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{719743f u0 com.simplifymindfulness.melatonin/.service.RescheduleAlarmsService}
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2070)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7806)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:958)
       
       
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException$ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{d633d2a u0 com.simplifymindfulness.melatonin/.service.RescheduleAlarmsService}
       at android.app.ActivityThread.generateForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException(ActivityThread.java:2242)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2213)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2505)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
       
       
Caused by android.app.StackTrace: Last startServiceCommon() call for this service was made here
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1988)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService(ContextImpl.java:1933)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:839)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService(ContextWrapper.java:839)
       at com.simplifymindfulness.melatonin.broadcastreceiver.AlarmBroadcastReceiver.startRescheduleAlarmsService(AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java:120)
       at com.simplifymindfulness.melatonin.broadcastreceiver.AlarmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(AlarmBroadcastReceiver.java:35)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4881)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleReceiver()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2417)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

This is My AlarmBroadcastReceiver::

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String MONDAY = "MONDAY";
public static final String TUESDAY = "TUESDAY";
public static final String WEDNESDAY = "WEDNESDAY";
public static final String THURSDAY = "THURSDAY";
public static final String FRIDAY = "FRIDAY";
public static final String SATURDAY = "SATURDAY";
public static final String SUNDAY = "SUNDAY";
public static final String RECURRING = "RECURRING";
public static final String TITLE = "TITLE";
private static final String TAG = "AlarmBroadcastReceiver";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String toastText = String.format("Alarm Reboot");
            Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startRescheduleAlarmsService(context);
        } else {
            String toastText = String.format("Alarm Received");
            Toast.makeText(context, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(RECURRING, false)) {
//                startAlarmService(context, intent);
//            }
//            else {
//                if (alarmIsToday(intent)) {
//                    startAlarmService(context, intent);
//                }
//            }
        startAlarmService(context, intent);
    }
}

private boolean alarmIsToday(Intent intent) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    int today = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    switch (today) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(MONDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(TUESDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(WEDNESDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(THURSDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(FRIDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(SATURDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(SUNDAY, false))
                return true;
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}

private void startAlarmService(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Log.e("TAG", "startAlarmService: ");

        Intent intentService = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        intentService.putExtra(TITLE, intent.getStringExtra(TITLE));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            try {
                context.startForegroundService(intentService);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "startAlarmService: "+e.getLocalizedMessage() );
            }
        } else {
            context.startService(intentService);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "startAlarmService: " + e.getMessage());
        try {
            OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ReminderWorker.class).build();
            WorkManager.getInstance(context).beginWith(work).enqueue();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            Log.e("TAG", "startAlarmService: " + x.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

private void startRescheduleAlarmsService(Context context) {
    Intent intentService = new Intent(context, RescheduleAlarmsService.class);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        try {
            context.startForegroundService(intentService);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "startRescheduleAlarmsService: "+e.getLocalizedMessage() );
        }
    } else {
        context.startService(intentService);
    }
}
}
```

NOTE: This is where startForeground is called this is triggered when alarm/notificationis triggered:

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private Vibrator vibrator;
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannnel();

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);

        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //to open difernce activity
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);

        String alarmTitle = "Melatonin Alarm: Listen Calm Music Now";

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setContentTitle(alarmTitle)
                .setContentText("Ring Ring .. Ring Ring")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_24dp)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) // Show on lock screen
                .build();

        mediaPlayer.start();

        long[] pattern = {0, 100};
        vibrator.vibrate(500);

//        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(1,notification);

        try {
            startForeground(1, notification);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        mediaPlayer.stop();
        vibrator.cancel();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannnel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "CHANNEL_ID",
                    "CHANNEL_NAME",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not always fixable, but there may be problems in `RescheduleAlarmsService` that are contributing to the frequency of your error. When are you calling `startForeground()`?

Comment: In alarm service when notification is triggered :     try {
            startForeground(1, notification);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+e.getLocalizedMessage() );
        }

Comment: You might want to move that to `onCreate()` -- your `Log` line suggests that you are doing it in `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Hi please check updated question description, as you said yes i have added in onStartCommand so are you telling me , i would have to put whole code inside onstartcommand into onCreete() ? will it work cause i see people trying this with no luck still i can try and roll the update.

Answer (score 0):

You [have to call `startForeground`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#start) when your `Service` starts to actually make it run in the foreground. `startForegroundService` just starts that service.

> **Inside the service**, usually in `onStartCommand()`, you can request that your service run in the foreground. To do so, call `startForeground()`. This method takes two parameters: a positive integer that uniquely identifies the notification in the status bar and the `Notification` object itself.

You have a few seconds to call `startForeground`, and if you don't, you get that error telling you you didn't do it. And that `Notification` is a requirement for a foreground service I'm afraid - Android 13 and up [allows **the user** to dismiss the notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#user-dismiss-notification) but the app can't just opt not to display one.

Comment: but many apps do it right withought showing notification, my only requirement is user can set particular time of day and it should work as reminder to just show notificaiton but simple code only work on google, motorola devices and majority of chinese devices fails

Comment: Im calling startforegorund when notification is triggered :     try {
            startForeground(1, notification);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+e.getLocalizedMessage() );
        }